# Loopback : adding data in relation table of type "hasMany"

Tags: json, api, loopbackjs

I have a table representing profil of users. This profils can follow others profils.

Here is a part of my profil.json

```
"relations": {
 "followers": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "Profil",
  "foreignKey": "publisherId",
  "keyThrough": "subscriberId",
  "through": "Subscribing"
 },
 "subscribings": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "Profil",
  "foreignKey": "subscriberId",
  "keyThrough": "publisherId",
  "through": "Subscribing"
 },
```

Well this works fine, but now I want to known the date when the profil was subscribed.

So I updated the subscribing.json relation table to add a date

```
 {
 "name": "Subscribing",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
 "options": {
   "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
  "subscriptionDate": {
    "type": "date",
    "required": true,
    "default": "$now"
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {
  "subscriber": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Profil",
    "as": "subscriber"
  },
  "publisher": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Profil",
    "as": "publisher"
  }
},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
```

}

Now I would like to be able to query the data of this profils while having the possibility to retrieve the date of subscription in the same time. Ideally, I would to keep the relation table non public.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add subscribers manually.

First, add the next to `subscribing.json`

```
  "scope": {
    "include": [
      "subscriber"
    ]
  }
```

Next, create the hook observer in `profil.js` (I use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for mapping but you can use your prefer library)

```
Profil.observe('loaded', function(ctx, next){
  const Subscribing = Profil.app.models.Subscribing;

  Subscribing.find({
    where: {
      publisherId: ctx.data.id
    }
  }, function (err, subscribings) {
    if(err) return next(err)

    ctx.data.subscribings = _.map(subscribings, function(subscribing){
      return {
        date: subscribing.subscriptionDate,
        subscriber: subscribing.subscriber
      }
    });

    next();
  });
})
```

And it's all! Try this and comment if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and make you some feedbacks. Just let me some time to digest it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "include" filter to add the relation data to the response.
So in your case this should get a user's 'subscribings':

```
Profil.find({include: 'subscribings'}, function() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: By doing this, I get the profil and subscribed profils, but not the date in the relation table.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now, maybe you should try looking at the following mixin. it seems to address the same issue of through model properties: https://github.com/JonnyBGod/loopback-set-through-properties-mixin

Comment: Thanks, seems interesting. I'll try this tonight and make you a feedback.

Comment: Well sorry for having been long to answer. Actually, it seems complicated to use mixins in the case of a hasManyThrough relation. Finally, even if I'm not confortable with that, the easiest way is to make the relation table public.

Answer (score 0):

One way is mentioned by @rigobcastro in his answer.

Alternatively, you need to create a new relation.

Let's say we call it `SubscribingMetaData`

In your profile.json, add following

```
 "subscribingMetaData": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "Subscribing",
  "foreignKey": "subscriberId"
 }
```

Now you can include it in your query,

```
Profil.find({include: ['subscribings', 'subscribingMetaData']}, function() { /* ... */ });

// process subscribingMetaData and map subscriptionDate with subscribings to get desired output.
```